# How can I stop my Facebook notification from appearing on friend's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I am in a group on Facebook, where my friend has joined. I want to get notifications from the group about what I post there, but do not want my friends to get notified about it.

I Google'd it and found that the only way to do this is to ask them (my Facebook friends) to turn-off the notifications from the specific group which I want to restrict notifications.

Is there a way by which I can manually control when the notifications appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no other way. See the privacy options available for groups https://www.facebook.com/help/www/220336891328465 which works even without the notification setting.